# Spring RabbitTemplate is not creating dead letter queue with TTL

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using spring-rabbit1.1 and RabbitMQ 3.3.1 ,

My spring configuration will create any queue with the help of RabbitTemplate on Rabbit MQ but if the queue has been configured with x-dead-letter-exchange and x-message-ttl , it just creates the queue with out the TTL and dead letter exchange.

For Eg : the below queue will create the queue but TTL and dead letter exhange is not getting created .

```
<rabbit:queue name="hello.queue.dead">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="hello.activity-task.topic"/>
        <entry key="x-message-ttl" value="10000"/>
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>
```

So i had to go and delete the queue from Rabbit MQ and create with all the required values manually to make it work .

Can anyone help me if there is any option to solve this issue ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly declare the queue and exchange...

```
<rabbit:queue name="q.with.dlx">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments> 
        <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="dlx"/>
        <entry key="x-message-ttl" value="10000" value-type="java.lang.Long"/>
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>

<rabbit:queue name="dlq"/>

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="dlx">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding key="q.with.dlx" queue="dlq"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

This assumes you routed the original message using the default direct exchange (routing by queue name). Hence the dead letter routing uses the same routing key (queue name). If you route using an explicit routing key, you would use that.

By the way, the `RabbitTemplate` does not declare these elements, it's the `RabbitAdmin` instance.

Comment: Hi Gary , 
thanks for you prompt response . i want to add the full xml configuration , i wanted to know how spring can help me create the queue with TTL and DLX on rabbit MQ .

Comment: I already had the same configuration as you advised but the queue just create with out any arguments.

Comment: While I knew it would work, I tested the configuration above before I answered. It just works. You must have something mis-configured. I suggest you use a combination of DEBUG logging and the RabbitMQ management UI to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Gary , can you help me once again i used your configuration , it created exchange but not the queue . what do you think i am missing , any example or link that you can share that will help me to get exchange and queue created dynamically from spring on rabbit mq . the other thing is will it change the queue by adding ttl to the queue if it is already there on rabbit mq.

Comment: I used the exact configuration you can see above, together with a `RabbitAdmin` bean (and connection factory, of course). I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging; the `RabbitAdmin` emits debug logs when making declarations. No, `RabbitMQ` rejects attempts to change queue arguments; the queue has to be deleted and re-added.

Comment: i missed the pom configuration for the spring-rabbit jar , this is the reason  it did not show up any logs in the debug mode , its working now thank you

Comment: Furthermore, since its'a direct exchange, you may need to specify dead-letter-routing key to "q.with.dlx" by adding a new entry with a key x-dead-letter-routing-key

Comment: Here, you used `xml` file.  I am using spring-boot, no xml files. Is it possible to do analogical configuration as your in java config ? Maybe, I also should use a xml to configure queue ?

Comment: There are many examples for using Java Configuration in the reference manual, such as [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#collection-declaration).