# Put unacknowledged message(on exception) to a different queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

On exception while processing the message from RabbitMQ, i just wanted to unacknowledg and put back the particular message to a difference queue instead or re-queue to same queue or completely discard the message(as per the last Boolean flag@requeue in basicNack).

The whole idea is later on i can get the count of unack message and check the message format etc instead of re-queue again and again to same channel and also i want to sent unacknowledged signal to current channel.

FYI I set the channel ack mode as manual(i.e container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);)

This is what i am doing now.

```
public class My***Listener implements ChannelAwareMessageListener{

try{

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message,Channel channel) throws Exception {   
    String s = new String(message.getBody());
    //some logic
    //after successful ack manually
    channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(),false);
    }
catch(Exception e){
      //currently on exception i am unack the channel
      channel.basicNack(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(),false,false);
}
```

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Just as a commentary on this question- what you are really asking is  the best way to "get the count of unack message and check the message format," so I would start with that and specifically clarify what methods you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send them to a dead letter queue. It's a pretty standard pattern.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

Comment: Thanks Enno, Currently i am using spring-amqp, so i am neither doing any exchange setup  nor queue deceleration(except setting the queue name to container)from coding side. Is there any similar way in spring-amqp?

Comment: @Lambodar: You can configure your policy directly on the broker rather than in your code that uses spring-amqp (see link for details). IMO that's preferable to configuring it in your code.

Comment: @EnnoShioji Tell me please, if each rejected message is sent to `DLX` ? No matter type of exception ?

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
@Bean
RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .withMaxAttempts(5)
            .setRecoverer(new RepublishMessageRecoverer(amqpTemplate(), "bar", "baz"))
            .build();
}
```

**Notice**: It works only with `spring-amqp 1.3+`
see also the [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#async-listeners)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use declarations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858880/spring-rabbittemplate-is-not-creating-dead-letter-queue-with-ttl/24865715#24865715) for an example.

To route messages to the `DLX`, you can set `defaultRequeuRejected` to `false` (on the listener container). Or you can throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` to tell the container you want this message to be rejected (and not requeued).

The container's default behavior is to requeue rejected messages.

You can use a retry interceptor with a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` to automatically throw the exception; or, as @Jawo99 says, you can use a republish recoverer - this has the added benefit of adding the stack trace as a header. The DLX just routes the original message.